# How to add Unsubscribe link at the bottom of transaction email footer?

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I'm trying to set up "unsubscribe link" to my email footer to my newsletter subscriber.  But, I cannot find any section regarding unsubscribe link or unsubscribe page.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Adding unsubscribe link in custom email magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110819/adding-unsubscribe-link-in-custom-email-magento)

```
<a href="{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}">
{{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}}
</a>
```